# How do I use the same custom types in two crates and implement foreign traits for them in only one?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am writing a client (using `mogwai`) and server (using `actix-web`) for a web application. The client and server will be exchanging messages of many custom types over a websocket (using `rmp_serde`). Ideally, I want to only have to define these message types once and import them into both the client and server library. The problem is, on the server side these types need to implement certain traits from `actix`, and on the client side, they do not. If I just define the types in a third crate and import them into both, I would have to build all the dependencies of `actix` when compiling the client (and yes, they would build separately because the client and server are compiling for different targets: `x86-64` and `wasm32`) just to compile trait implementations I wouldn't use. I've been thinking of using something like crate features, but that feels too hacky for what seems like it should be a simple problem. What am I missing?

Comment: What am I missing? Nothing. I would just say I don't like actix. Unless, your use of actix is wrong, nothing in what you said is wrong.

Comment: Using `features` for this is common and accepted in the Rust ecosystem. See, for example, every library with a `serde` feature.